# Exception: Failed to send email: no subject

Tags: html, google-apps-script

It keeps error with code
[Exception: Failed to send email: no subject sendEmail @ automated.gs:9].
Im not sure what the error happening here or if I missed out anything.

It does send email to receiver but the email content is empty.

Comment: Please post your code or a jsfiddle for us to find the error properly.

Comment: SendEmail function take at least 3 args,recipients, subject, body.  Do you miss anything ?